# Excel VBA manual calculations

Tags: excel, vba

I want to speed up my macro by using manual calculations until the end, but there's a part where I break links from another workbook. I tried to do this, but it just turned back empty cells instead. Am I not able to use manual calculations when breaking links? Sorry if this question was asked I was having difficulty finding something on it

Answer (score 2):

If you broke a link to an external Excel, you can't retrieve the data anymore. It actualy deletes any formulas. For instance, if you have a 2 Workbooks (Book1 & Book2) with 10 in cell A1 of Book1 and `=[Book1]Sheet1!$A$1` in cell A1 of Book2, if you go to Data > Edit Link > Break Link the warning message is quite clear

> Breaking links permanently converts formulas and external references to their existing values. Because this cannot be undone, you may want to save a version of this file with a new name.

And then the value in cell A1 of Book2 got converted to `10`. Changes in Book1 will not appear in Book2 anymore